# Using angularjs to create horizontal radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building a set of radio buttons using the ngRepeat directive and I need to make it horizontal.  I'm not sure it's possible to do that with ngRepeat, since each instance gets its own scope.  The below structure creates a new div for each item in the options array and they're displayed vertically.

```
<div ng-repeat="option in options">
    <input type="radio" role="radio" />
    <span>label</span>
</div>
```

Does anyone know any tricks for creating horizontal radio buttons?

Answer (score 6):

Angular doesn't really affect style in this way. Give your div `float:left` or `display:inline-block` in its style.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that AngularJS from version 1.1.6 up allows one to do this much more cleanly:

Assume

```
$scope.data = [{val:0,txt:'Foo'},{val:1,txt:'Bar'},{val:2,txt:'Baz'}];
```

then you can use repeat-start and repeat-end like this:

```
<input ng-repeat-start="item in data" type="radio" value="{{item.val}}">
<span ng-repeat-end>{{item.txt}}</span>
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/rWLfZ/